# Mage2SalesOrder: Customer Prefix is too long (maximum is 32 characters)

Tags: magento2, data-migration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptj7E.jpg)

I'm migrating through magento2 db from magento1 using UB Data Migration Pro

Getting this error Mage2SalesOrder:

> Customer Prefix is too long (maximum is 32 characters)

For more detail I also attached the code file.

Comment: Still I'm on step , with same error